# Swift : Error with ParseUI and utf16Count not present

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

```
 func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, shouldBeginSignUp info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Bool {
    if let password = info?["password"] as?  String
    {
        return password.utf16Count >= 8
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}
```

.utf16Count > not present 
I wrote  return password.utf16 >= 8

Error ::: Binary Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type string,UTF16View' and 'int'

Comment: Reading the Xcode 6.3 beta release notes would solve the problem quickly ...

Comment: thank you but am beginner can you help with that , I just read and try but I couldn't can give post answer if thats ok , I'll be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Xcode 6.3 beta release notes:

> utf16Count is removed from String. Instead use count on the UTF16 view of the String.

So you have to replace

```
return password.utf16Count >= 8
```

by

```
return count(password.utf16) >= 8
```